# AttributeConverter being ignored for com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point

Tags: mysql, jpa, geolocation, point, jts

i want to be able to read column of type "POINT" from MySql database,

i wanted to write an AttributeConverter for that, so i started by printing the values from the DB, but my AttributeConverter is never called, so nothing is printed to the screen.

Here is my configuration

```
spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
spring.jpa.show-sql=false

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb
spring.datasource.username=myuser
spring.datasource.password=mypassword
```

here is my Entity code

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Convert;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Index;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.dateup.models.converters.PointConverter;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;

@Entity
@Table(
    indexes={@Index(name = "name", columnList="name")}
)
public class City {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long id;

    public String name;

    @Convert(converter=PointConverter.class, attributeName="location")
    @Column(name="location", nullable=false, columnDefinition="Point")
    public Point location;
}
```

this is my beginning of my 'PointConverter'

```
@Converter(autoApply=false)
public class PointConverter implements AttributeConverter<Point, byte[]>  {

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PointConverter.class);

    @Override
    public byte[] convertToDatabaseColumn(Point point) {
        logger.error("======= convertToDatabaseColumn    ---- ");
        System.out.println("convertToDatabaseColumn");
        System.out.println(point);

        if (point == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            Geometry geom = (Geometry) point;

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int SRID = geom.getSRID();

            try {
                byte[] buf = new byte[4];
                ByteOrderValues.putInt(SRID, buf, ByteOrderValues.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
                bos.write(buf);

                WKBWriter writer = new WKBWriter(2, ByteOrderValues.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
                writer.write(geom, new OutputStreamOutStream(bos));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // should be impossible
                throw new UnhandledException(e);
            }

            return bos.toByteArray();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Point convertToEntityAttribute(byte[] dbData) {
        logger.error("======= convertToEntityAttribute    ---- ");
        System.out.println("convertToEntityAttribute");
        System.out.println(dbData);

        if (dbData == null) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(dbData);
            byte[] buf = new byte[4];
            is.read(buf);
            int SRID = ByteOrderValues.getInt(buf, ByteOrderValues.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
            WKBReader reader = new WKBReader();
            Geometry ret = reader.read(new InputStreamInStream(is));
            ret.setSRID(SRID);

            return (Point) ret;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UnhandledException(e);
        }   
    }
}
```

my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
<artifactId>myapp_data</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>myapp_data</name>
<description>myapp data service</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
        <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vividsolutions</groupId>
        <artifactId>jts</artifactId>
        <version>1.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.firefang</groupId>
        <artifactId>ip2c</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>/Users/x/eclipse_workspace/myapp/lib/ip2c-2.0.0.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

this is the error that i am getting, should AttributeConverter help solve this error ?

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00000000
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:806) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:309) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:299) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:27) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:234) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2738) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.loadFromResultSet(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:306) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.hydrateEntityState(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:233) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.readRow(AbstractRowReader.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.EntityLoadQueryDetails$EntityLoaderRowReader.readRow(EntityLoadQueryDetails.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3967) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.immediateLoad(SessionImpl.java:997) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:157) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:266) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at com.dateup.models.City_$$_jvsted8_2.toString(City_$$_jvsted8_2.java) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2981) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at com.dateup.repositories.SearchService.searchForUsers(SearchService.java:150) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.dateup.repositories.SearchService.search(SearchService.java:105) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.dateup.controllers.SearchController.search(SearchController.java:37) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_20]
```

also checking the data in my DB using this query

```
SELECT AsText(location) FROM City limit 2;
```

returns

```
               AsText(location) 
---------------------------------------------
'POINT(1.4873600006103516 42.55329895019531)'
'POINT(1.5739200115203857 42.53219985961914)'
```

and of course

```
SELECT count(*) FROM City WHERE location IS NULL;
```

returns

```
count(*)
--------
0
```

so my data seems valid

---

updating the question 
settings

```
@TypeDefs({
      @TypeDef(name="point", typeClass=GeometryUserType.class)
})
```

and

```
@Column(name="location", nullable=false, columnDefinition="Point")
@Convert(converter=PointConverter.class, attributeName="location")
@Type(type="point")
public Point location;
```

and using a

```
public class GeometryUserType implements EnhancedUserType {
....
public Object nullSafeGet(...){
                InputStream is = rs.getBinaryStream(names[0]);
            if (is == null)
                return null;
            byte[] buf = new byte[4];
            is.read(buf);
            int SRID = ByteOrderValues.getInt(buf, ByteOrderValues.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
            WKBReader reader = new WKBReader();
            Geometry ret = reader.read(new InputStreamInStream(is));
            ret.setSRID(SRID);
            return ret;
}
```

i see the point is converted in GeometryUserType. nullSafeGet method, but the value is null in my model....

why @TypeDef partially working and AttributeConverter is not. what i am missing

Can someone please help me !!
Thank you

Comment: the Converter and Convert annotations.. from package they are from?

Comment: updated the question all from "javax.persistence"

Comment: please add the package of entity and converter and "'SpringBootConfiguration class.. with package and imports

Comment: i didn't define any "SpringBootConfiguration", that do you mean ?  i am using the file application.properties , updating question now

Comment: The column in the database has the type point (binary data, you need `AsText` to actually read it), but your converter expects a string, so that's mismatched. You can use hibernate-spatial which supports the point out of the box. https://github.com/chaodhib/Hibernate-Spatial-5-Sample

Comment: at first look, you should just use the Hibernate custom type, without the converter. Removing it could be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i did as @approciblue say, i looked at 'benizra' response http://techqa.info/programming/question/39147145/spring-data-jpa-and-geometry-type  (which very helped).

help  my to understand the when loading

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

will provide the dialect class that will know how to work with the location object, all left to do is to configure those new classes in the `application.properties`

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQL5InnoDBSpatialDialect
```

so now this is my City class

```
@Entity
public class City {    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public State state;

    public String name;
    public String accentName;

    @Column(name = "location", columnDefinition = "POINT")
    public Point location;
}
```

thank you